# Displaying Specific Fields from Facebook Graph API JSON

Tags: winforms, facebook-graph-api, json.net

I'm trying to simply display the list of members in a specific group using the Facebook Graph API. I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Here is the results of my url query:

[Graph API Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGiFp.jpg)

I used a JSON class generator and it gave me this:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool administrator { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
}

public class Members
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Members members { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried every combination I can think of to display simply the list of members in a multi-line text box, but not sure if this is even the best way to display the list on a Windows Form App.

Could someone help me understand 2 things.

1) What is the best component to display the list of names in a Windows Form App?

2) What is the 1 or 2 lines to generate just the list of names using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject from this?

My raw data is stored in:  `string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deserialize the JSON into your classes:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseFromServer);
```

To get the member names into a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> members = obj.members.data.Select(d => d.name).ToList();
```

Note: You need to have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file in order to use the `Select` and `ToList` methods.

As far as displaying the data in a windows form app, there's not a "best" component-- it depends on what you're trying to accomplish as to what control you would choose to use.  For example, if all you want to do is display the list of names in a multi-line textbox, you could do this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", members);
```

If you want to allow the user to be able to select individual names and do something based on that selection, you would probably want to use a ListBox or a ComboBox instead.   You can populate a ListBox or ComboBox like this:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
listBox1.DataSource = obj.members.data;
```

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Brian! This worked perfectly. I've edited my original question with a follow-up if you have any spare time. I appreciate the time already. Basically, I've tried adding more information into the web request and it returned a more complex data structure that I'm having trouble working with.

Thanks again!

Comment: If this answer has sufficiently addressed your original question and you have a new follow-up question, you should close this question (click the checkmark icon to the left of the answer), then use the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page to ask your follow-up question.  It is a new question and will have a different answer.  By mixing the two questions together it becomes confusing as to what parts of the answer(s) apply to what parts of the question, particularly to someone new who is reading the question/answer for the first time and trying to follow along.