# Displaying Specific Fields from Facebook Graph API JSON at Multiple Levels

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, json.net

I'm trying to display some information using the Facebook Graph API. I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Here is the results of my url query:

```
 {
   "albums": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "Album 1",
            "photos": {
               "data": [
                  {
                     "id": "686123475970"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "686203123490"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "686212345870"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "612343620880"
                  },
                  {
                     "comments": {
                        "data": [
                           {
                              "from": {
                                 "name": "John Smith",
                                 "id": "10206512123464061"
                              },
                              "message": "Test Comment 1 string value",
                              "id": "1571234466083854"
                           }
                        ],
                        "paging": {
                           "cursors": {
                              "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVFUzTlRVNU1EUTJOakE0TXpnMU5Eb3hORGN6TkRZAMk5EWTQZD",
                              "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVFUzTlRVNU1EUTJOakE0TXpnMU5Eb3hORGN6TkRZAMk5EWTQZD"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "id": "612343615890"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "686203123430"
                  },
```

Here is the JSON Structure I got from a generator:

```
public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Datum3
{
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public List<Datum3> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors2
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging2
{
    public Cursors2 cursors { get; set; }
}

public class Photos
{
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
    public Paging2 paging { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Photos photos { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors3
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging3
{
    public Cursors3 cursors { get; set; }
}

public class Albums
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Paging3 paging { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Albums albums { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

[With help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39292958/10263), I was able to retrieve a list of members from a different JSON structure using this code:

```
RootObject1 obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject1>(responseFromServer);
List<string> members = obj.members.data.Select(d => d.name).ToList();
CurrentMembersDisplay.Text = string.Join("\r\n", members);
TotalMemberCount.Text = members.Count.ToString();
```

Ultimately, my end goal is to display the name of the commenter, the album they commented in, as well as the comment only IF the comment contained a certain keyword.  So I'd like to see something like "John Smith - Album 1 - Comment"

I'm having a hard time linking these 3 items together as they're at different levels.

Is there any way someone might be able to help me out with this?

Comment: Need more info-- First, please post your JSON as text, not as a redacted image.  It's OK if you anonymize the data and cut it down for size as long as it still is a good representation of the data structure and is complete, i.e. open braces/brackets match close braces/brackets throughout.  This will make it much easier for us to help.  Second, what "album" and "keyword" are you referring to?  Neither your JSON nor your classes have any mention of these things.  Where does this data come from?

Comment: Hi Brian,I will try to generate this again and post as text. Apologies, the album is in the URL and I can just grab that and post it, so no need to worry about that. The keyword would be in the message text. So ultimately from my example above, I would want to display the linked message that contains any sort of keyword that I chose, but it can be hardcoded. So really, I need help getting at the "from" field under the message structure and the message itself. It all be string data. I'll work on getting the structure again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again Brian. I've posted the new code and results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on whether you are more comfortable with good old fashioned loops or you prefer more concise LINQ code.

Here is the traditional way using loops:

```
public static List<string> GetComments(RootObject root, string keyword)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (Datum a in root.albums.data)
    {
        foreach (Datum2 p in a.photos.data)
        {
            if (p.comments != null)
            {
                foreach (Datum3 c in p.comments.data)
                {
                    if (c.message.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        list.Add(c.from.name + " - " + a.name + " - " + c.message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here is the equivalent way using LINQ methods:

```
public static List<string> GetComments(RootObject root, string keyword)
{
    return root.albums.data
        .SelectMany(a => a.photos.data, (a,p) => new { Album = a.name, Comments = p.comments })
        .Where(p => p.Comments != null)
        .SelectMany(p => p.Comments.data, (p,c) => new { Album = p.Album, From = c.from, Message = c.message })
        .Where(c => c.Message.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        .Select(c => c.From.name + " - " + c.Album + " - " + c.Message)
        .ToList();
}
```

You can use the above code like this:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
List<string> comments = GetComments(root, "test");
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", comments);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RgimOG

Comment: Hi Brian,

I edited the question to include the JSON with the album name. I didnt realize i could grab it from the source instead of the URL. So technically, it could have 10 albums or more in this structure. Apologies for not noticing that earlier.

Comment: @Dshel7702 I've updated my answer to handle multiple albums.  Hope this helps.